# Invoice line item addition through api

Tags: netsuite

Trying to add a new line item to an existing invoice

```
PATCH /services/rest/record/v1/invoice/7902 HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com

{
"item": {
    "items": [ 
        {    
            "item":{"id":"625"}, 

            "amount": 2.54
        }
    ]
}

}
```

Error :

```
"detail": "Error while accessing a resource. You have entered an Invalid Field Value 625 for the following field: item.",
            "o:errorPath": "item.items[0]",
            "o:errorCode": "USER_ERROR"
```

The item with id does exist
can anyone help.

Tried looking through their API doc too.